# Getting "Couldn't read CGI input from STDIN" while processing Post request using HTTPClient in android

Tags: java, android, html, post, httpclient

I am currently developing an android application, to submit a post request and to handle the corresponding response.

I am able to hit the post request to the corresponding URL, But when I am trying to retrive the response, I am getting half of the HTML content followed by "***Couldn't read CGI input from STDIN.AFTER ALLOC_READ 0***"

Could anyone please help me to solve this issue.

Here are the code snippets

```
private void processRequest(String... params){

        HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://www.xyz.com");
        HttpParams httpParams = post.getParams();
        pnr = params[i];
        httpParams.setParameter("param1", params[i]);
        //User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:14.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/14.0.1
        httpParams.setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.USER_AGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:14.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/14.0.1");

        post.setParams(httpParams);
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

        try {
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);

            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();


            try {
                processHtmlString(pnr, inputStreamToString(entity.getContent()).toString());
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally{
            client.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
        }
  }


   private String processHtmlString(String pnr, String htmlString) throws Exception{

    int index = 0;
    while(index < htmlString.length()){
        int endIndex = (index + 3000) < (htmlString.length()) ? (index + 3000) : htmlString.length();
        Log.i("HttpHelper1","HTML1 : "+htmlString.substring(index, endIndex));
        index += 3000;
    }
    }
```

and the output is
    ...........Couldn't read CGI input from STDIN.AFTER ALLOC_READ 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you arent forming the request correctly (you are putting params into the same section headers go, and not in the body):  try this.

```
    List<NameValuePair> bodyParams = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    bodyParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("param1", params[i]);
    if (bodyParams.size() > 0) {
        try {
            // Include the request body
            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(bodyParams));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Body parameters produced unsupported encoding?", e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much "forgivegod". The Code is working fine :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use Strings, use InputStream provided by the entity itself. A String is limited in length and this probably causes your problems. Read directly from the stream.